# rsync "unknown module" error

Tags: rsync

I use rsync for backing up the data from servers to a backup machine. For that purpose I start bash scripts via cronjobs but one of them is not working. I searched through the web to see if there is a solution but I couldn't find one, so I thought it'd be a good idea to post it here.

```
#!/bin/bash

KDIR=/usr/cron
LOCKDIR=$KDIR/lockdir
LOCKFILE=$LOCKDIR/filename.lock
if [ -f $LOCKFILE ]
then
    exit 0;
fi
touch $LOCKFILE
RSYNC_PASSWORD=<passwd> rsync -vvv --delete -aW --old-compress \
  --compress-level=4 \
  rsync://rsyncod@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Directory1/Subdirectory1 \
  /STORAGEDIRECTORY/storagesubdirectory

rm -rf $LOCKFILE
```

and the error i got:

```
@ERROR: Unknown module 'home'
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at
main.c(1635) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

oh, the dir I want to backup is a subdirectory to `/home/`

Comment: Don't you lack a space character between `--compress-level=4` and `rsync://...`?

Comment: no, that's just the way it was posted,

rsync -vvv --delete -aW --old-compress --compress-level=4 rsync://rsyncod@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Dir/Subdir /storedir/substordir

Comment: Consider passing `--dry-run` option to `rsync` when testing your command so that you don't do anything crazy (see `man rsync` for explanations).

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Sure. My `--dry-run` advice just means that while you're unsure of your command, you might as well dry-run it until you validate it, especially since you use the `--delete` option. I mean imagine you make a mistake, maybe just a typo, and you end up deleting your source. This option does not address your issue. Consider it as a side comment.

Comment: When dealing with such scripts, you may also want to start the important line with `echo` so that it echoes the constructed command line instead of running it and you can inspect it before running it for real. E.g.: change the rsync line into `echo RSYNC_PASSWORD=<passwd> rsync -vvv...` and you'll see what actually happens. Then you can run the command alone (with `--dry-run`) and see what happens. I'm not giving you the answer to your issue, here, just hints as how to debug. Excuse me if all of this seems obvious to you. Maybe it isn't to someone else.

Comment: what does the `/etc/rsyncd.conf` look like on the remote host?  this is probably an error in that.

Comment: I posted it as answer because I couldn't as a comment.

Comment: You could update your question (`edit` option). When pasting code, please use the "code formatting" option represented by the {} icon up the edition box. Basically what it does is prepending each line with 4 spaces to indicate it should be represented as code. The 4 spaces is the markup syntax for code. The {} icon is a convenience as it adds the spaces for you so you don't need to do it manually on each and every line.

Comment: try defining a `[home]` section in `rsyncd.conf`

Comment: Does your `rsync` command actually reference something called `Directory1` or is that a replacement for the true path? If it's a replacement, does the bit you removed start with `/home` by any chance? Please [edit] your question to provide the extra information.

Comment: The directory I want to backup a subdirectory for /home
Does that answer your question?